# Setting a SSI server variable

Tags: html, apache, ssi

I'm using SSI to include some footer files from the client. The footer files have the following condition:

```
<!--#if expr="$SHOW_PAGE == 'true'" -->
```

I can't change the footer files so I have to provide the $SHOW_PAGE variable. I've tried setting it in my main file:

```
<!--#set var="$SHOW_PAGE" value="false" -->
```

as well as in the .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv SHOW_PAGE false
```

But neither of those method is working. How do I set that variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `set` directive is wrong, it should be:

```
<!--#set var="SHOW_PAGE" value="false" -->
```

(no `$` sign in front of the variable name in the declaration).

To set it in the `.htaccess` for it to be guaranteed to be found, you need to rename the variable to have the prefix `HTTP_` otherwise it won't be passed through to your SSI pages. Ie., your variable needs to be `HTTP_SHOW_PAGE` both in the .htacces file, and your SSI pages. In your case, since you cannot edit the footer pages, you would do something like:

```
<!--#set var="SHOW_PAGE" value="$HTTP_SHOW_PAGE" -->
```